# Cannot use json.map

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, typescript-typings

I have `typescript` code to load `mapbox` and have `Json` from the back end

Here is how I define variable now:-

```
 const json: any = gon.hotel_info;
```

And use it like this, in this code:-

```
 data: {
        type: "FeatureCollection",
        features: json.map((item): any => {
          return {
            type: "Feature",
            properties: {
```

But I don't want to use any typedefs and try to use it like this

```
const json: JSON = gon.hotel_info;
```

But now I have an error with JSON map

> Property 'map' does not exist on type 'JSON'.

How I can fix it?

Comment: Maybe try a type that has the `.map` method. Like `Array`

Comment: But Generic type 'Array<T>' requires 1 type argument(s) , but which one?@chbchb55

Comment: Idk, I was just guessing, I'm a noob with TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer to my question. Answer is install mapbox-gl-js types and use code like this

```
  const json: Array<GeoJSONGeometry> = gon.hotel_info;
```

and after - this

```
  features: json.map((item: GeoJsonProperties): Feature => {
```